# Capitalize placeholders

Tags: html, css, browser

I want all place-holders texts to be capitalized. So I've created a css style:

```
input[placeholder] { 
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

However, they're still in lower case. Why? At the moment I'm in Chrome but  I'd like it to work for all major browsers.

P.S. It capitalizes the text I enter. But I want it to capitalize a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: should I keep my css style as well?

Comment: if you mean the line you wrote above input[placeholder] , no you have to remove it , it's not valid selector

Answer (score 1):

You could style the placeholder--

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: initial;
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  
   text-transform: initial;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}
```